# Why do I need to "hdparm -r" in order to mount a Sony camcorder read/write and why is it dangerous?

Tags: linux, camera, hdparm

When I plug my Sony camcorder into my Linux systems, the file system gets mounted read-only. I cannot simply mount it read-write, I first have to use "hdparm -r0" to make the "device" read-write. Why is this so and why is "hdparm -r0" considered "dangerous"?

"dmesg" output follows.

1. Plugging the device in.

```
[ 1371.786740] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1371.875813] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0830
[ 1371.875822] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1371.875827] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB Bus-powered Device
[ 1371.875832] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Sony
[ 1371.875835] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: ************
[ 1371.879120] input: Sony USB Bus-powered Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input21
[ 1371.879552] hid-generic 0003:054C:0830.0006: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Sony USB Bus-powered Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[ 1372.377533] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

2. Turning the device on.

```
[ 1395.073294] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 1395.159821] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=08de
[ 1395.159831] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1395.159837] usb 2-1.2: Product: HDR-AS100V
[ 1395.159840] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Sony
[ 1395.159844] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: ************
[ 1395.198826] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1395.198936] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 1395.199078] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 1396.202342] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Sony     Camcorder        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1396.218549] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Sony     Camcorder        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1396.219347] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1396.220185] sd 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1396.305975] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 123795456 512-byte logical blocks: (63.3 GB/59.0 GiB)
[ 1396.306358] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] 102400 512-byte logical blocks: (52.4 MB/50.0 MiB)
[ 1396.307338] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is on
[ 1396.307346] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 80 00
[ 1396.308599] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] Write Protect is on
[ 1396.308605] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] Mode Sense: 03 00 80 00
[ 1396.309579] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 1396.309586] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1396.310725] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[ 1396.310733] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1396.316948] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 1396.316965] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1396.317962] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[ 1396.317979] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1396.319865]  sdc:
[ 1396.320881]  sdd: sdd1
[ 1396.325818] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 1396.325831] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1396.325849] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1396.328067] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[ 1396.328077] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1396.328083] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1396.749464] SELinux: initialized (dev sdc, type fuseblk), uses genfs_contexts
[ 1396.782748] SELinux: initialized (dev sdd1, type vfat), uses genfs_contexts
```

3. Mounting the device read/write.

```
# mount -o rw,remount /dev/sdc
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdc read-write, is write-protected
# hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
# mount -o rw,remount /dev/sdc
#
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question pops up in searches for `hdparm -r`:

the `-r` flag has been marked as dangerous between hdparm versions 2.3 and 2.9 (years '95-'96 - ancient!) with no elaboration, but the actual operation performed is the same to this day.

It calls `ioctl(fd, BLKROSET, &readonly)`

The same can be done with

- `blockdev --setro DEVICE`
- `blktool DEVICE readonly on` ([requires patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=641164))

The BLKROSET is one of the core ioctls that has been part of the Linux kernel since [0.96c-patch1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/0.96c-patch1/source/include/linux/fs.h#L96).

This ioctl seems to get forwarded to the underlying block device driver [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.155/source/block/ioctl.c#L441), so, depending on the driver, it might actually reconfigure the target storage device.

However, I didn't go that far into the madness that is the [Linux storage device stack](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Storage_Stack_Diagram) to actually confirm that, and I couldn't find any anecdotal evidence to support that.

So, I would consider it safe to use.

---

Do note that until recently, there was a pretty nasty bug in the scsi driver (so, most standard hard drives) where the read-only flag wouldn't stick:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198689
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1548938

It was fixed, but the fix has caused a new bug that forced some devices to stay read-only

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201221
- https://www.spinics.net/lists/stable/msg283998.html

Check if your kernel has been patched against these issues.