# Mark entire SATA disk as read-only on the disk itself

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sata, read-only, hdparm

Is there a way to mark an entire SATA disk (a Samsung SSD in my case) as read-only on the drive itself, such that it will be write-protected no matter which computer I will put it in? I know there is `hdparm -r`, but the man page does not state what it actually does (I suspect it to be a temporary linux kernel setting of some sort). I would like a logical switch equivalent to those physical ones on some SD cards or USB drives.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/742987) seems related, but is still unanswered.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question (yet) but you may find this interesting: [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries) includes read-only flag for every partition (bit 60). Although I cannot tell which OSes and tools respect the flag.

Comment: I want to preserve the current state of the disk. Converting it to GPT would defeat the purpose. Otherwise it would mostly cover my use case if Linux respects the RO flag.

Comment: I didn't want to defeat the purpose. There was a chance you already had GPT.