# Write protect an internal hard drive independent of OS

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

We would like to write protect the internal hard drives in the machines in a class environment. The machines are dual boot, running both Windows and Linux (RedHat).

We are looking for ways to protect the HDDs in such a way that nothing can be written to these in either of the OSs. Just to be specific, we also need to protect the disks from commands like [`fdisk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdisk) or [`parted`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html). We also want to prevent accidental deletion of files and folders.

The machine users have administrative access. So, password protection is not an option.

(The specific scenario is, the main hard disk is `/dev/sda` and the scratch one is `/dev/sdb`. While practicing disk partitioning in Linux using `fdisk` and `parted`, a few of the students go for `/dev/sda` even after being instructed repeatedly to go for `/dev/sdb`.)

We don't want to write protect other drives including the USB sticks which are often attached to these machines.

Comment: What are you planning to do about tmp files and swap space?

Comment: Related, no answer yet: [*Mark entire SATA disk as read-only on the disk itself*](https://superuser.com/q/1114459/432690).

Comment: @DavidPostill That creates a contradiction I must say.

Comment: Run from a CD or DVD... but, as mentioned before, swap, temp and other areas need write access. A common work-around is to restore an image periodically. If the boot partition is small enough, that could be done between classes.

Comment: Have the machines automatically run a VM that's set to discard any changes on shutdown, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you are asking - at least not without hardware which is not commonly available.

The closest I could find was forensic hardware to plug your SATA disk into a (forensics) USB converter which might work if you have internal USB ports.

An alternative might be to modify the workflow and do all the training in VMs. Another alternative might be to modify your systems to PXE boot against read-only backends.

Answer (score 1):

For just Windows, you can use Deep Freeze - it works well for us in our lab environments.

Unfortunately, it depends on the drivers, etc. loaded for it to prevent actual writing to teh hardware.  You can get around it by writing from a different OS - like your dual boot setup.

This would still work for you if you were to move the linux stuff to virtual machines (VirtualBox or VMWare) with just the sole Windows OS as the host.  Then the hard drives can be frozen, users can do work even as Windows admins, and on machine reboot, it is back to the way it was frozen.

When we first evaluated DF 15+ years there was a hardware solution that went between the hard drive adn the controller cable, using an actual lock to lock/unlock the write ability.  This would still work no matter what OS is being run or how it was booted (ie, live linux system on cd) but I'm not sure if it is offered anymore.